# Difference between storing reference to pointer beforehand vs referencing pointer on-the-go

Tags: pointers, go, reference

First, hopefully, the question's title makes sense (feel free to suggest edits). I have never dealt with pointers manually before, just learning Go.

So, is doing the following:

```
func something() {
  something := *thing
  go func() {
    for err := range something.Errors() {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
  }()
}
```

...have any advantage over:

```
func something() {
  go func() {
    for err := range (*thing).Errors() {
      fmt.Println(err)
    }
  }()
}
```

Note that I have tried doing `*thing.Errors()` in second case, but it gives me error unless I put braces around it (which is understandable since `Errors()` method doesn't return any pointers, I guess?).

---

Although this is micro-optimization that I would normally not care about, but for learning and curiosity purposes, won't the second case have more performance overhead (since its referencing pointer on every iteration)?

What is `thing`, you ask? Most likely a struct, or could be an interface or could be anything (I know that certain components such as maps, strings, functions, structs etc. are passed by reference by default. But I would still like to know for those components that are not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Errors` is in [the method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) for `*thing` then you can use `for err := range thing.Errors() { ... }`.

Because the [range expression is evaluated once at the beginning of the loop](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range), there should be no difference in performance between the two snippets in the question and my suggestion in this answer.